# How are unsubscribe links are constructed?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, frontend

How do unsubscribe link works?

I would like to know how an unsubscribe link maps to a user without the use of cookies. I know it has something to do with encrypted string in the link. I am curious about if there is some standard/good practice I should follow while creating such links.

Following are some examples..

```
http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Unsubscribe.aspx?tg=30458880345&l=3
http://stackexchange.com/email/manage/126398/f5b119aca8179fad3ae6580843826519b97946c0bc490087ffe2111
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually just a random token stored in a database to map it to a specific account.